# Show that $S_n$ is not cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I know that showing this idea very basic(as shown in method 1), but I tried something to do with "odd,even" permutation.

***My question is*** proof of ***Lemma 4*** in ***Method 2***. (Proof have wrong logic or not.)

> **$\star$Method 1:**
> Using contrapositive proof method.
>
> ***Theorem:***
>
> If a group $G$ is cyclic, then it is abelien.
>
> ***Contrapositive:***
>
> If a group $G$ is not abelien, it is not cyclic.
>
> Since $S_n$ is not abelien for $n>2$ it is not cyclic for $n>2$.$\Box$

---

***$\star\star$Method 2***: Using $3$ wellknown permutation group theorem and additional key lemma (lemma 4)

***Theorem 1:*** Every permutation can be written by product of transpositions.

> ***Proof:***  Let $f=\left (f_n \; f_{n-1}\; ... f_3 \;f_2\;f_1\right)$ and for arbitrary $n\in\mathbb N^+$  $f$ is equal to $(f_{2}\;f_{1})(f_{3}\;f_{1})(f_{4}\;f_{1})....(f_{n-1}\;f_{1})(f_{n}\;f_{1})=\left (f_n \; f_{n-1}\; ... f_3 \;f_2\;f_1\right)$$\Box$

***Theorem 2:*** Every permutation is written either odd or even number of transpositions

> ***Proof:*** Omitted, it can be found, it is a little bit long.$\Box$

***Lemma 3:*** For $n>2$ every $S_n$ has even and odd permutations.

> ***Proof:***  $S_3$ has $(123)$ which is even and $(12)$ which is odd. Since $\forall n>3$,$S_n$ consists $S_3$, $S_n$ has even and odd permutations. $\Box$

---

***Lemma 4:*** Every power of a permutation is the same polarity. That is, $f$ be permutation, and $P(x)$ be polarity function that shows permutations odd or even.
$P(f)=P(f^2)=....=P(f^{d-1})$ where $o(f)=d$ (order of $f$)

***Proof:*** Using $o(fg)=lcm(o(f),o(g))$ rule, I prove only for odd permutation's powers, since the proof for even permutations is the same.

Assume that $f$ is odd permutation, that is order of $f$ is even. $o(f^2)=lcm(o(f),o(f))=o(f)$ that is order of $f^2$ is even and so permutation $f^2$ is odd permutation. $\Box$

---

***Main Theorem:*** $S_n$ is not cyclic $\forall n>3$

***Proof:*** Assume that $S_n$ is cyclic for some $n>3$ so there must be an element that generates $S_n$, let call this element as $g$ and by assumption $<g>=S_n$ but it is wrong because $g$ can only generate like its polarity(recall $P(x)$ in ***lemma 4***) (that is, if $g$ is even permutation, $g$ can only generate even permutation but there is odds ass well (***lemma 3***), and for $g$ is odd, logic is the same.)$\Box$

---

Comment: Your lemma 4 is false. The product of two odd permutations is even.

Comment: Why did you hide the proofs of the Lemmata ?

Comment: @Peter, because they are proven in a lot of book, I wanted to consantrate to the point.

Comment: @DavidHill Can you give a counter example because I cannot see what you wanted to say, since the two permutation must be the same $ff=f^2$  and after writing in disjoint transposition, their polarity do not change. For example, if you thought that $(12)(34)(56)\circ (12)(34)(56)$ it is not counter example since this permutation is order two, and in lemma 4 it is forbidden $P(f^k)=P(f^n)$ where$0<k,n<order(f) $

Comment: Lemma 4 is indeed wrong as any odd permutation not of order $2$ shows. Anyway, I am not sure I see the idea in going this deep on a trivial statement like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof using cycle decomposition:

- Every permutation is the product of disjoint cycles.
- Every cycle in $S_n$ has order at most $n$.
- The order of a product of disjoint cycles is at most the lcm of the orders of the cycles.

Therefore, the order of every permutation in $S_n$ is at most $lcm(1,2,\dots,n) < n!$ because $lcm(1,2,3,4) < 4!$.

Unfortunately, this argument needs $n \ge 4$. The case $n=3$ is easy.

Here is a proof that works for $n \ge 3$:

- $S_n$ has at least two elements of order $2$: $(12)$ and $(13)$, but a cyclic group has at most one element of order $2$.